# Making an href tag dynamc in VB

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, href, stringbuilder

I'm new to VB so I apologize in advance if my terminology is not the best when it comes to VB.

I have an href link that I am currently trying to make dynamic. Previously I tried using an `asp:HyperLink` but I was having issues with the HyperLink as I was not able to link a title and kept seeing `example-link.com` instead of `VIEW ARTICLE`.

I've done some research and appears that doing a string builder approach will be the way to get the result that I am expecting. I am having issues with the string builder at the moment.

Here is a break down of what I am trying to accomplish

---

Example of a static link that I am trying to re-create dynamically.

`<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><a href="/how-to-develop/" target="_self" title="How to Develop">VIEW ARTICLE</a>`

---

My attempt with an ASP:HyperLink:

`<asp:HyperLink ID="MyListUrl" runat="server">View Article</asp:HyperLink>`

Codebehind for HyperLink

```
Public Class Links
    Public Property MyListId As Integer
    Public Property MyListRecommendation As String 
    Public Property MyListSummary As String 
    Public Property MyListUrl As String 
End Class

 Protected Sub InitializeTrendsListsObject() 

 If MyLists.MyListId = 1 Then ' How to Develop
      MyLists.MyListUrl = "/how-to-develop/"
 ElseIf MyLists.MyListId = 2 Then ' How to Code
      MyLists.MyListUrl = "/how-to-code/"      
End Sub
```

---

My attempt with string builder:

`<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><asp:Literal ID="ltMyListURL" runat="server"></asp:Literal>`

Code behind

```
Protected Overloads Function BuildRecommendation (ByVal reports As DataTable, ByVal counter As Integer, ByVal isExec As Boolean) As String

        Dim htmlBuilder As New StringBuilder
        Dim endLoop As Integer = 1

        If isExec Then

            For Each report As DataRow In reports.Rows

                If Not endLoop.Equals(counter) Then

    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<p class='trends-list-item-summary'>" + report(2).ToString() + "... <a 
    class='trends-list-item-more' href='" + MyList.MyListUrl+ report(3).ToString() + "/' 
   target='_blank' title='" + report(0).ToString() + "'>View Article</a></p>")

                    endLoop += 1 ' increment controller by 1
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

            ' Close content container
            htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</div>")

        End If

        Return htmlBuilder.ToString()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not clear what you attempt to do, but I hope is this what you want:

```
Protected Overloads Function BuildRecommendation(ByVal reports As DataTable, ByVal counter As Integer, ByVal isExec As Boolean) As String

    Dim htmlBuilder As New StringBuilder
    Dim endLoop As Integer = 1

    Dim sConst As String = "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'>{0}</i> <a href='{1}' target='_self' title='{2}'>VIEW ARTICLE</a>"

    If isExec Then

        'Open the content container
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<div>")

        For Each report As DataRow In reports.Rows

            If Not endLoop.Equals(counter) Then

                htmlBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format(sConst,
                                                     report(2).ToString(),
                                                     MyList.MyListUrl & report(3).ToString(),
                                                     report(0).ToString()))

                endLoop += 1 ' increment controller by 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        ' Close content container
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</div>")

    End If

    Return htmlBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Is the string builder approach the correct way of going about making an href dynamically?

Comment: If you need the given string as result by this function as InnerHtml of another control  and the generated “dynamic” controls are managed by Client side(via Javascript)  Yes. Otherwise you need to create Asp Controls by code if you want to have access by .NET